# WordPress Lite/Light

Tags: functions

Does anyone ever thought about releasing a new WordPress Lite or Light which will not be bloated with ALL this unnecessary stuff? Would be cool to be a "WordPress for Developers" where we can write our own functions to get things done. So wp will only have basic things included. I'm thinking: No comments, no customizer, no gutenberg, no exporting/importing, maybe no Users, no theme editor, and so on. Maybe have an alternative to ACF to fill content, just as an idea.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the WP basics and essentials, what do you want to use WP for? Why don't you use a different system then? Also, why did you thought of this? If because of speed/performance you are free to use the WP REST API which is in core. Additionally you can have a look at other CMS or even framework to build your custom needs.

Comment: customizer it's not something from wp basics, i don't use it often, also widgets, comments, import/export, etc. I love WordPress, but I think a lot of things are useless, and I would love to have a wordpress without all those. It's just my oppinion.

Comment: Most of the functions are not loaded if you don't need them, aren't on the admin area or or at a certain page. So an alternative would be to simply hide the menu items.